# How to make the datagrid with no data?

Tags: asp.net

I have a page with two buttons: one is `Load Data` and the other `Clear Data`.

I am using DataSet and have used ds.Tables.Clear() in that click code.

If the user clicks `Clear Data` will the data in the datagrid disappear or not?

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 0):

For showing grid with no rows, check [GridView.EmptyDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate.aspx) Property

or

You can create an empty row and add to your datagrid like this -

```
if(datatable.Rows.Count == 0)
{
    datatable.Rows.Add(datatable.NewRow);
}
datagrid.DataSource = datatable;
datagrid.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, the answer is No.